# tFileOutputDelimited Output Stream to tGoogleDrivePut

Tags: google-drive-api, talend

I am writing a Talend job that needs to take data from Salesforce and create a txt file in Google Drive. I am using tFileOutputDelimited configured like below:
[Job Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bx4N.png) [tFileOutputDelimited](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxXid.png)

I also have the tGoogleDrivePut configured as such:
[tGoogleDrivePut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgLG9.png)

The error:

```
Starting job Orion_File_Dump_Google_Job at 15:21 15/04/2020.
[statistics] connecting to socket on port 3989
[statistics] connected
Exception in component tFileOutputDelimited_1 (Orion_File_Dump_Google_Job)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.Writer.<init>(Writer.java:88)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.<init>(OutputStreamWriter.java:97)
    at monthly_closings.orion_file_dump_google_job_0_1.Orion_File_Dump_Google_Job.tSalesforceInput_1Process(Orion_File_Dump_Google_Job.java:8544)
    at monthly_closings.orion_file_dump_google_job_0_1.Orion_File_Dump_Google_Job.runJobInTOS(Orion_File_Dump_Google_Job.java:53974)
    at monthly_closings.orion_file_dump_google_job_0_1.Orion_File_Dump_Google_Job.main(Orion_File_Dump_Google_Job.java:53798)
[statistics] disconnected

Job Orion_File_Dump_Google_Job ended at 15:22 15/04/2020. [exit code  = 1]
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you share more information on what is going on? What is the code giving the error?

Comment: I have attached the images that are configured on Talend. Those show the configuration of the objects. My thought is that the GoogleDrive component from Talend is actually not functioning correctly, but I am looking for either confirmation or how I have it configured incorrectly.